# How to implement BeaconConsumer with service in android

Tags: android, service, ibeacon-android, background-service

I am using BeaconConsumer with Activity and it working fine. While as I implement BeaconConsumer with service, it not working.

```
SimpleService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {


protected static final String TAG = "MyBeaconService";
String UUID = "EXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";
private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBeaconManager.setDebug(true);
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
    Log.e("", "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart called");
    mBeaconManager
            .getBeaconParsers()
            .add(new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed ...");
    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.e("", "onBeaconServiceConnect");
    mBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "didEnterRegion");
                mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "didExitRegion");
                mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

        }
    });

    mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons,
                Region region) {
            for (Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {

                Log.e("", "setRangeNotifier");
                Log.e("", "ID 1" + oneBeacon.getId1());
                Log.e("", "ID 2" + oneBeacon.getId2());
                Log.e("", "ID 3" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                Log.e(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance());
                Log.e("",
                        "oneBeacon.getBluetoothAddress() :- "
                                + oneBeacon.getBluetoothAddress());

            }
        }
    });

    try {
        mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region(
                "myBeaons", Identifier.parse(UUID), null, null));
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myBeaons",
                Identifier.parse(UUID), null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This will not working. It did not gives details of beacon, instead of that its show this in logcat - 
Logcat Message

> 04-09 11:07:40.053: D/BeaconParser(8765): This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201061aff4c000215e2c56db5dffb48d2b060d0f5a71096e000000000c5020a000816f0ff640000000011094d696e69426561636f6e5f30303933370000
>   04-09 11:07:40.648: D/BluetoothAdapter(8765): onScanResult() - Device=F2:75:FA:D7:6E:19 RSSI=-45

So, how may i use BeaconConsumer class with service so i get all details of beacon when app is close or not. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `setBeaconLayout` line in the `onCreate` method.  **Depending on how your start your service, the `onStart` method may not get called.  The `onCreate` method always gets called.**

You may also wish to add some logging in these methods so you fully understand the startup sequence of your service during troubleshooting.